# bigWig to bed for regions above/below threshold

Tags: bed, bigwig

I'd like to threshold a bigWig file on a value and get all regions above or below that value in bed format. Ideally without too many file conversions. Are there any tools to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Bioinformatics. What have you found? Where did you look up ? (To avoid looking at the same sites) What have you tried? I think that we have some other questions in this site about bed and bigwig. Aren't they helpful?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/282410/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a bit of python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyBigWig
threshold = 10  # Change me
bw = pyBigWig.open("file.bw")  # Change me
of = open("regions.bed", "w")  # Change me

for chrom, len in bw.chroms().items():
    intervals = bw.intervals(chrom)
    for interval in interals:
        if abs(interval[2]) > threshold:
            of.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(chrom, interval[0], interval[1]))
bw.close()
of.close()
```

You'll need to install pyBigWig (it's available via `pip` or `conda install`) and change the lines with `Change me` in them.

Answer (score 1):

Convert bigWig to WIG via [`bigWigToWig`](https://www.encodeproject.org/software/bigwigtowig/):

```
$ bigWigToWig signal.bw signal.wig
```

Convert WIG to BED via BEDOPS [`wig2bed`](http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/conversion/wig2bed.html):

```
$ wig2bed < signal.wig > signal.bed
```

Filter BED by its score column with `awk`:

```
$ awk '($5 < 1)' signal.bed > signal.filtered.bed
```

The test `$5 < 1` filters elements from `signal.bed` that have a score value less than `1`. Change this to the threshold test you would want to apply.